# How does updating the state in a reducer trigger a re-render of the component(s)?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I understand that mapstatetoprops is mapping our Redux application state to our React component props, but i don't quite understand what's happening behind the scenes when a reducer returns a new state - how does that trigger a re-rendering of components that have props mapped to the application level state?

In pure React, setState triggers a re-render correct?  Is something similar (or the same thing) happening via Redux?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both `Redux` and `React-Redux` employ shallow equality checking.

In particular:

`Redux's combineReducers` utility shallowly checks for reference changes caused by the reducers that it calls.

`React-Redux's connect` method generates components that shallowly check reference changes to the root state, and the `return values from the mapStateToProps` function to see if the wrapped components actually need to re-render. Such shallow checking requires immutability to function correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Well the whole point when you create a component using the redux "connect" function, is that behind the scenes you get connected to the redux state, and have a listener for the state changes.

So you create a simple component that gets his values from props, but those props are got from the state using the connect with "mapStateToProps".

Never dived in to the redux-react connect function, but if you want you can surely go ahead and see what it does exactly.

But the main point is what I explained above.